# How to run code when jquery slideUp() finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideup

is there any way to execute `html()`, only when `slideUp()` will be finished?

```
<p class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tortor elit</p>
```

```js
$(".test").slideUp().html("");
```

I tried did it with Deferred and queue, but I failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it within the [animation complete callback](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/#slideUp-duration-complete).

```
$(".test").slideUp(function(){ 
  $(this).html(""); 
});
```

```js
$(".test").slideUp(2000,function() {
  $(this).html("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tortor elit</p>
```